# Taylor series with Fibonacci coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be the Fibonacci numbers given by $a_0=0,a_1=1,a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ for $n\geq 0$. Prove that $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\ldots$ is a rational function, and determine which rational function it is.

So we have $f(z)=z+z^2+2z^3+3z^4+5z^5+8z^6+\ldots$. The Hadamard formula says that the radius of convergence is $R=1/\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}=1/\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio, since the Fibonacci grows as powers of the golden ratio.

But how can we find which rational function $f(z)$ is equal to?

Comment: Just use Binet's formula for Fibonacci sequence: $$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - (-\varphi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: That works, but is a bit of overkill. Ross's answer below lets you see why you get Binet's formula...

Comment: But how does this radius of convergence gives you that $f$ is a rational function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  $f(z)=zf(z)+z^2f(z)+z$, which you can prove using the Fibonacci recurrence.